# How do I convert an R "network" object to an "igraph" object?

Tags: r, import, igraph, sna

How do I convert an R "network" object to an "igraph" object?

Many formats are discussed in the [tutorial](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/igraphbook/igraphbook-foreign.html) and [package documentation](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc/R/read.graph.html), but I couldn't find how to import a "network" object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the [intergraph package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/intergraph/index.html).

Note that this package claims to be compatible with the obsolete `igraph0` version of igraph, but since the igraph objects are exactly the same in the `igraph0` and the `igraph` packages, objects created with `intergraph` should work in `igraph` as well. (I never tried personally.)

You can load the `igraph0` and the `igraph` packages at the same time, just make sure that you are calling the `igraph` functions and not the `igraph0` functions in your code. An easy way is to load `igraph0` first, `igraph` next, and then the `igraph0` functions will be masked. Or you can unload the `igraph0` package via `unloadNamespace()` when you don't need it any more.

Answer (score 0):

```
Net <- network.initialize(10, directed = FALSE) #initialize a graph with 10 nodes
```

Then run

```
asIgraph(Net)
```